# How to dispay current user only name to send Email in workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to display current user name on my email body but it show full name with other some data i am new in SharePoint can you please tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Add or Change look 
 Return Field as "Display Name" I thing you select string there.